# what is the advantage of octane 90 petrol vs octane 95? how it effect to fuel consumtion of a car?

Tags: engine, maintenance, ignition, fuel-consumption, carburetor

i need to know about advantages of octane 90 petrol VS octane 95 or unleaded. how it effect to fuel consumption of a car?

Answer (score 0):

Lower octane fuels have no advantages other than being cheaper. Higher octane fuel simply makes it possible to run more advanced ignition timing, and therefore allows you to get more performance out of an engine, but you won't notice a difference in fuel consumption unless your car's software has been customised or you have a Carburetor specifically adjusted for higher octane fuels.